# Transfer function help

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function

I've been trying to model a circuit where I'm getting the gain of a non-inverting op amp connected to two probes. I've isolated the following feedback circuit and am trying to work out the transfer function for it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Jim Brown - Hi, Please don't remove the question's content after it has been answered. Part of the point of Stack Exchange is to collect questions and their answers *for the future*. I have reversed that edit. Attempting to remove the question is classed as vandalism and is not allowed. Please don't do that again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determination of the transfer function is quite complicated if you consider the open-loop gain of this op-amp - otherwise there is no fun : )

I have used the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs to obtain the complete transfer function, ignoring, of course, the internal op-amp ac response, only its open-loop gain \$A_{OL}\$:

[image]

For a very large open-loop gain, the dc gain simplifies to that of a non-inverting configuration \$\frac{R_1}{R_2}+1\$ and the pole is pushed to infinity. If the capacitor is now increased to 1 µF with an open-loop gain of 100k, despite the high-value of the capacitor, the pole will be located at 1.24 MHz. This circuit is a classic to improve robustness of op-amp-based circuits to capacitive loading. It is discussed [here](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/techniques-to-avoid-instability-capacitive-loading.html).

Comment: With pleasure but in your sketch - now it is alone - we don't know where is the stimulus (the input) and where is the response (the output)? In lack of op-amp, it is a simple \$RC\$ low-pass filter.

Comment: Perhaps, but the op-amp adds its active part and changes the ac characteristics: you cannot dissociate the two.