# Expression of a feedback circuit

Tags: transfer-function

I'm modelling a feedback circuit in Ltspice, however, I want to work out the transfer function for it. See below for the circuit.
[image]

Now I want the form of Vfb/VOA_o as:
[image]

So, I've thought about breaking up the circuit into two constituents to solve for this, as follows.

[image]

Would you say that this is the best way to approach this? What is the transfer function, if this is not the correct approach?

Comment: It looks like a duplicate already answered [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/686632/transfer-function-help/686658#686658). You cannot separate the circuit into two separate paths as you do here.

Comment: thanks for your response. I've had a read of your reply to the other thread with this, however, I am still unsure of how it answers my question. I'm looking for the transfer function in a certain format, so how would you approach stipulating it in such a fashion?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "a certain format"? This is a 1st-order system and I presented the result in a clear and ordered form. What did I miss?

Comment: what I mean is, I am trying to express it in the format shown above - a voltage divider multiplied with 1/(1+s/wp)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Find the transfer function for Vout/OA_ and then multiply it by a factor of 1/2 to get the transfer function for fb/OA_

Comment: thanks for your response, just have a question, why do we multiply by 1/2 for the final form of fb/OA?

Comment: alanwake29261 The 2 Rs form a resistive voltage divider. fb = Vout*R/(R+R)

Comment: oh alright, could you possibly outline it with the corresponding steps?

Comment: @alanwake29261 Vout/OA_ = (Zc//2R)/(Rout+(Zc//2R)) then multiply your derived transfer function by 1/2.